# What services do I need to setup the backend?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, backend

This is probably a duplicate question but I am not sure how to word this question properly to get the right answer...

So I am a mobile developer I haven't coded much in the backend or setup my own database and server.

I asked a contractor to code up my backend. I need a place for my database and a place to store the API/Server so that I can access it on the mobile app using the API. For some reason they are asking about MongoDB, GCP and stuff like that.

All I need is a backend where the database is stored and a server that has API endpoints that can do REST.

Many thanks probably a dumb question.

Comment: 1/2) The number of options is significant. Which option to choose requires more information than present in your question. If your developer has designed in MongoDB, then that choice is made for you. For the backend server, Compute Engine is usually the **safe** choice but not always the **best** choice. Since your developer designed the system, ask him to help you deploy the solution. Bugs/issues often appear during the deployment and testing phase.

Comment: 2/2) MongoDB: https://cloud.google.com/mongodb This lab will give you an indication of how to use Compute Engine: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-compute-engine#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All I need is a backend where the database is stored and a server that has API endpoints that can do REST.

MongoDB is a document-oriented NoSQL database. You and your developer can install your MongoDB [manually](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-google-cloud/) in Google Compute Engine vm instance or through the [marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace)(with help of deployment manager) named [MongoDB](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/click-to-deploy-images/mongodb) or [MongoDB Atlas](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/mongodb/atlas-pro), see the images below. This is where your database is stored. Here's another [one tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-atlas-appengineflex-nodejs-app?hl=en_US&_ga=2.6069171.-1818056499.1626805904) how to install and use MongoDB Atlas with App Engine.

[image: MongoDB]
[image: MongoDB Atlas]

For backend server, John Hanley is right you can use the Compute Engine but there are other services such as Cloud Run and App Engine that much cheaper than Compute Engine because it will charge you base on the requests that you made. You can use [GCP Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to estimate the cost of your GCP products or services every month.

**REST API REFERENCE:**

1. [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/getting-started)
2. [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/rest-in-the-api)
3. [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest)